# Chrome Developer Tools magnifying glass has disappeared from Chrome 32

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I just updated to Chrome 32.0.1700.76 m (on Win7) and Developer Tools has changed.

Particularly painful is the disappearance of the Magnifying Glass icon for inspecting elements in the page. There's also no mention of it the Shortcuts list.

Anyone have any info as to where this has gone, and/or how to re-enable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Inspect Element icon is now found at the upper-left corner of the devtools.

[image: magnifying glass in upper-left corner]

Comment: Yessssssss! It's pretty obvious, now that you point it out :)

Comment: How can I found this feature now?

Comment: @Diogo Same corner, different icon (a square with an arrowhead through it) - at least in Chrome 50.

Answer (score 0):

Click on developer tool area and simply `CTRL + "+"` for Zoom in and "-" for Zoom out for Windows and `Command + "+"` for Zoom in and "-" for Zoom out for Mac.